# Generalization of method of least squares to matrix system (Pseudo inverse?)

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

A and B are two m$\times$n real matrices with m > n.
I need to find X: a real m$\times$ m matrix such that $\| A - X B\|$ is minimized.

On thing I'm thinking about is using the singular value decomposition of B to compute its pseudo-inverse and then saying $X = A B^\dagger$. Is there any way of proving that this minimizes the system? Is there another better way?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Which matrix norm are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 1-norm

Answer (score 0):

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse minimizes the 2-norm, so this wouldn't be correct even if A and X were vectors. Minimizing the 1-norm requires linear programming.